# XML update a set of nodes in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this PHP code that adds a set of nodes to an XML file. It does most of what it should do, it finds where to make the additions, but then it doesn't make the update.

I have an xml file of this structure.

```
<COMMUNITIES>
  <COMMUNITY ID="c001">
       <URLS>
           <URL ID="u001">
              <NAME>Google.com</NAME>
              <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
           </URL>
       </URLS>
  </COMMUNITY>
</COMMUNITIES>
```

The updates are being made to the URLS node.  The user clicks an "Add URL" link and I add the new URL to this node like this.

```
       <URL ID="u002">
          <NAME>Yahoo.com</NAME>
          <URL>http://www.yahoo.com</URL>
       </URL>
```

If the URLS node exists, I append the new url node. If the URLS node does not exist, I create it, then append the new url node.

There are no errors, everything seems to work, but the URLS node is empty.  Here is the PHP script.

```
function add_url( $nodeid, $urlid, $urlname, $urllink ) {

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('communities.xml');

$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// get document element  

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']"); 

if ($nodes->length) {
   $node = $nodes->item(0); 

   $xurl = $dom->createElement("URL"); 
   $xurl->setAttribute("ID", $urlid);

   $xuname     = $dom->createElement("NAME");  
   $xunameText = $dom->createTextNode(mysql_escape_mimic($urlname));  
   $xuname->appendChild($xunameText); 

   $xulink     = $dom->createElement("URL");  
   $xulinkText = $dom->createTextNode(mysql_escape_mimic($urllink));  
   $xulink->appendChild($xulinkText); 

   $xurl->appendChild($xuname); 
   $xurl->appendChild($xulink); 

   $xurls = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']/URLS");

   if ($xurls->length) {
   }
   else {
      $xurls = $dom->createElement("URLS"); 
   }

   $xurls->appendChild($xurl);

   /* $node->appendChild($xurls); */

}

$dom->save('communities.xml');
}
```

I thought the problem was that I was appending the URLS node when it already existed.  But I commented out that line.  I am sure the problem is simple, but I am new at this.  I looked on the site and did not find that specific situation.

**Edit**

1. Removed return statement before `if ($xurls->length)`.
2. Fixed function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was attempting to add nodes to a node which was already in the XML file as empty.

Instead of the node having data like this.

```
<URLS>
   <URL ID="u001">
      <NAME>Google.com</NAME>
   </URL>
</URLS>
```

I had a node like this.

```
<URLS/>
```

Common sense says that this should not be a problem. If the node is empty then appendChild should just add the data and rewrite the node as.

```
<URLS>
   <URL ID="u002">
      <NAME>Yahoo.com</NAME>
   </URL>
</URLS>
```

Here is the PHP script that worked.  You will note that I created a new node instead of appending to `<URLS/>`.  I also reordered the appendChild to start from the top node instead of the creating the child nodes first then appending a set of nodes to the top node.

```
function add_url( $nodeid, $urlid, $urlname, $urllink ) {

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('communities.xml');

$dom->formatOutput = true; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

// get document element  

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']"); 

if ($nodes->length) {

   $node = $nodes->item(0); 

   $xurls = $xpath->query("//COMMUNITY[@ID='$nodeid']/URLS");


   if ($xurls->length) {
   }
   else {
      $xurls = $dom->createElement("URLS"); 
      $node->appendChild($xurls);
   }

      $xurls = $dom->createElement("URLSC"); 
      $node->appendChild($xurls);

   $xurl = $dom->createElement("URL"); 
   $xurl->setAttribute("ID", $urlid);
   $xurls->appendChild($xurl);

   $xuname     = $dom->createElement("NAME");  
   $xunameText = $dom->createTextNode(mysql_escape_mimic($urlname));  
   $xuname->appendChild($xunameText); 
   $xurl->appendChild($xuname); 

   $xulink     = $dom->createElement("URLC");  
   $xulinkText = $dom->createTextNode(mysql_escape_mimic($urllink));  
   $xulink->appendChild($xulinkText); 
   $xurl->appendChild($xulink); 

}

$dom->save('communities.xml');
}
```

So I must modify the function that creates the empty node `<URLS/>`.  I should not create the node in that function but create it here in the add_url function only when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `return` half way down the function, before you have actually saved the changes - so I'd guess what is happening is that you are making the modifications in memory, but not actually writing them to file...

Comment: I added that return statement to debug the script.  I removed it and the URL isn't added.

Comment: what could be the problem with this script?

Comment: Wish I could help but i've just been over it again, and honestly I have no idea. I don't really ever work with PHP's DOM functions, so I'm a bit lost...

Comment: I've isolated the problem to that this call to appendChild `$xurls->appendChild($xurl);`.  I thought that the problem was the name.  This node has the same tag as the parent node.  Changing the node name didn't help.  The only other thought is that I am appending a node that itself has two nodes each having a text node.  Is there a rule for the order in which to define the nodes then specify their value?  Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so in PHP, but if your worried about it I would do your `appendChild()`s from the top down - I know there are some issues in Javascript with this - notably you can't change certain attributes of certain DOM elements after they have been appended to the DOM.

Comment: The problem was the fact that I was adding nodes to an empty node, i.e. `<URLS/>`. AppendChild works if I add the data to a new node. I am making sure that if the `URLS` node has both open and close tags that this works.  The "save" function created the `<URLS/>` tag because there was no data added before the XML file was saved.

Comment: Makes sort of sense I suppose, but seems a little bit silly that it should behave like this to me - I mean if your node is short-tagged, surely PHP is intelligent enough to figure out that this should no longer be the case, and to expand it? Oh well, at least you got it sorted :-)